# How can I abstract my Navigation Drawer in another class that can be used by all my activities(Android)?

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

I have been able to create my navigation drawer following the example from AndroidDevelopers. I have to put this navigation drawer in all the activities, and in all of them, it will be exactly the same.

That's why I have thought about abstracting this part of the activity and setting a method such as showNavigationDrawer() in a different class, that would show all the navigation drawer. I don't know how to do this. Should I extend Activity in this new class or should I enter into parameters the activity and the context?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest to you using Fragment so you won't have this problem.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it without Fragments? Which are the advantages about using Fragments instead Activities in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[Same Navigation Drawer in different Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-on-different-activities)

Basically create a Base Activity implement Navigation drawer and other children activity inherit from this Base Activity.