# navigation drawer not showing in multiple activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

here is Drawer activity code
sliding:

```
public class sliding extends Activity {

// Within which the entire activity is enclosed
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

// ListView represents Navigation Drawer
private ListView mDrawerList;

// ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the
// action bar
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// Title of the action bar
private String mTitle = "";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_sliding);

}

void Drawer() {
    mTitle = "Care&Cure";
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

    // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when drawer is closed */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        /** Called when a drawer is opened */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("Care&Cure");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };

    // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(), R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources()
                    .getStringArray(R.array.menus));

    // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Enabling Home button
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // Enabling Up navigation
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and for main activity
    MainActivty:

```
public class MainActivity extends sliding implements OnClickListener {

ImageButton hosp, doc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Drawer();



    hosp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_hosp);
    doc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_doc);

    hosp.setOnClickListener(this);
    doc.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_doc) {
        Intent dc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sliding.class);
        startActivity(dc);
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bacground" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- 2 columns -->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_hos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:src="@drawable/hos" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_doc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:src="@drawable/doc" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_lab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:src="@drawable/lab" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:src="@drawable/b" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

logcat:

```
 08-26 14:25:24.268: W/dalvikvm(17531): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa8228)
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.careandcure/com.example.careandcure.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):  at com.example.careandcure.sliding.Drawer(sliding.java:78)
  08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):  at com.example.careandcure.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
  08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
  08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
  08-26 14:25:24.268: E/AndroidRuntime(17531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
```

i am following [Android Navigation Drawer with multiple activites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807043/android-navigation-drawer-with-multiple-activites/22807682#22807682) to create drawer in multiple activities its working fine in sliding but not in main activity..its giving `null pointer exception`. how to resolve it.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setContentView()` in the class that overrides `sliding`, where you pass a new xml file to be inflated (`R.layout.activity_main`). My guess is this xml file doesn't contain the layouts you require for your `sliding` `Activity`.

The example you are following is not a good one. You are trying have an Activity which hosts the NavigationDrawer, and then extend that Activity. The concept is fine, but your execution is wrong. Your slider class needs to be able to create and display a `NavigationDrawer` and still remain extensible, so you need to write it in such a way that overriding standard methods (like `onCreate()` and calling `setContentView()`) does not impact on the slider class's ability to display the `NavigationDrawer`.

I would suggest creating the `NavigationDrawer` in a fragment, and inflating that fragment in the `onCreate()` of your sliding `Activity`. That way the `NavigationDrawer` is fully contained within the fragment, and you don't have worry about which methods you override and what you do with them.

Comment: yup its fine can you link me good example for multiple activities

Comment: I don't know of any, but if I were you I would just set it up individually for each activity (just to get the hang of it). Refer to the developer docs: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: using fragment is very good idea , but problem is that how can i shift all my running activities to fragment.

Comment: Have you looked at the developer docs example? You don't move all your Activities to a Fragment, you move the Navigation Drawer to a Fragment and then reuse that Fragment in your Activities.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a button with id btn_hos and btn_hosp. It's giving a null pointer.

> hosp = (ImageButton) findViewById(**R.id.btn_hosp**);

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/btn_hos" <----------
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:background="@drawable/selector"
   android:contentDescription="@string/image"
   android:src="@drawable/hos" />
```