# How can I extend an activity which has a navigation drawer implemented?

Tags: android

I have two activities,one is a MainActivity which has navigation drawer working.The Other is a testActivity which extends from the MainActivity.When I move from the MainActivity to the testActivity the navigation bar appears there but not working when i click there.

I have read too many posts on this like [extending navigation drawer activity to other activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137283/extending-navigation-drawer-activity-to-other-activities) but I didnt understand them.

The following is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle t;
    private NavigationView nv;
    Button nextBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        t = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.string.Open, R.string.Close);
        nextBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextAct);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TestActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        dl.addDrawerListener(t);
        t.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        nv = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv);
        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.account:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.settings:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.mycart:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }


                return true;

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(t.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }




}
```

The following is the testActivity.

```
public class TestActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


    }
}
```

The second activity gets the navigation bar as i have extended this from the MainActivity but that is  not clickable in this new activity.Can any edit the code so that it will be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do this is to use fragments. The navigation drawer + bar stays the same, and you change fragments in the rest of the screen. Hope it helps !