# Why same Navigation Drawer is not Toggling from another activity in android?

Tags: android

I want to use same navigation drawer in multiple activities so I have implemented navigation drawer in MainActivity and extended this MainActivity in other Activities in which I want to use the same navigation drawer. 
When i Touch the Drawer Icon, it is highlighting but the drawer is not opening.

I have followed the code explained in this link: [Same Navigation Drawer on different Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19451842/3829152)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you create your ActionBarDrawerToggle.

I personally do it in `Activity.OnCreate()` like this:

```
if (mDrawerLayout != null) {//for large screens it is null
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 0, 0);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);
}
```

So in my case I should call super.onCreate() in the descendant class.

**Edit**

You may also look if all the methods of [DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html) are overridden correctly.

Still **it's not a standard way to use Navigation Drawer**. Make sure if your design is what you really need - **[fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)** are more flexible and easy to use. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-on-different-activities) is another related post.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have now implemented the same **using Fragments**. Its so easy.