# NullPointExeption in BaseActivity

Tags: android

I want create an `BaseActivity` with `Navigation Drawer` for extends other activities from this. (Use one Drawer for all activities)

I searched and tried many codes like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities) but i still have:

> Unable to start activity (NullPointExeption) error!

Also I write this code in `MainActivity`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
super.onCreateDrawer();
```

but it don't work :(

BaseActivity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public String[] layers;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    protected void onCreateDrawer()
    {
        // R.id.drawer_layout should be in every activity with exactly the same id.
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity) this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 0, 0) 
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) 
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.hello_world);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreateDrawer();
    }
}
```

drawer_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- Put what you want as your normal screen in here, you can also choose for a linear layout or any other layout, whatever you prefer -->
</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

Logcat:

```
   09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at com.example.test.NavigationActivity.onCreateDrawer(NavigationActivity.java:38)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-07 07:12:47.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

what's the solution?!
Thanks.

Comment: can you post the logcat report?

Comment: Post your **Log** to help you in better and right way.

Comment: Done! logcat added to question.

Answer (score 2):

The `NPE` could be easily caused by  `getActionBar()` depending on the version of the Android and your manifest's configuration. I strongly suggest you to extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`, and use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. Be aware that both can return null, depending of the Theme you selected on your manifest.

Comment: i use eclipse and eclipse don't have Android AppCompat v22.01 Library! how can i download it?

Answer (score 0):

Your getting error in **onCreateDrawer()** method. It can be because of:

1. Instead of extending **Activity** use **AppCompatActivity**
2. Instead of this line

> drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity) this,
>   drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 0, 0)

Make it like this

> drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
>   R.drawable.ic_drawer, 0, 0)

3. Check your theme, Use a theme which can support ActionBar Here is the Android Documentation link [Styling Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: AppCompatActivity is undefined for eclipse! i add android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" to application tag in manifest but yet the problem remains

Comment: You have to add the **Support v7 library** also.

Comment: I can't find Android Appcompat Support Library v7 ( 22.01 or higher ) for download!

Comment: You can download it from your **SDK Managaer** you can see **Android Support Library** option in that which you have to update to latest.

Comment: Developer.Android.com and related google website not accessible for Iran :| I want direct link for download Android Support Library v7 (22.01 or higher)