# How to extend a class from main application in an android library activity?

Tags: android, android-library

I've used this answer: [Same Navigation Drawer in different Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19451842/1699611) to implement a navigation drawer that is shown in all activities.

I am not sure if this is the right way to go, but at the moment I have a main application, that contains some activities and implements the `NavigationDrawer` in the `BaseActivity`.

I would like to start by creating many android library projects that will have activities/fragments in them and their own logic. So for now, besides the main application, I've created one android library project and I can successfully start one of its' activities from the main application (from the `NavigationDrawer`).

The problem is that I cannot make it extend the `BaseActivity` and therefore the `NavigationDrawer` is not shown.

So, at the moment in the main application, I have:

```
activity_main.xml // it is the launcher activity
activity_one.xml
activity_two.xml
MainActivity.java
OneActivity.java
TwoActivity.java
```

That works fine. Now I want to add the library project into play, in which I have:

```
activity_three.xml
ThreeActivity.java
```

And now the problem is that in the library project, I cannot extend from the `BaseActivity` like that:

```
public class ThreeActivity extends BaseActivity{ // <-- There's an error here: Cannot resolve symbol 'BaseActivity'

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_three);
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions how to do that?

Should I just create another library project that has the `BaseActivity` and the navigation drawer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I just create another library project that has the BaseActivity and the navigation drawer ?

Either that, or get rid of all the libraries and move everything into the one project. A library cannot inherit from classes from a project that *consumes* the library. A library can inherit from classes from a project that the library itself depends upon, though.

So, the `app/` module could depend upon the `three/` library (that has `ThreeActivity`), which in turn depends upon the `base/` library (that has `BaseActivity`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Just to make sure I understand - I should create a library project that has the `BaseActivity`. Then every other library could extend it. And then I can make one main project that also extends the `BaseActivity` project. I need to have them as libraries, because it will be easier to manage/maintain/develop in future.

Comment: @Apostrofix: "Then every other library could extend it" -- libraries don't extend other libraries. Libraries can depend upon other libraries. "And then I can make one main project that also extends the BaseActivity project" -- you would need the app project to depend upon all of the other libraries, directly (e.g., the one with `ThreeActivity`) or indirectly (e.g., the one with `BaseActivity`).