# Different toolbar for each fragment in navigation drawer

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, navigation-drawer

I have a MainActivity which has a NavigationDrawer. This NavigationDrawer is Synced with the Toolbar initially.  And i want to use the Only one NavigationDrawer across the whole Application. Now the Problem is that each fragment has the different toolbar or CollapsingToolbar.
I already read the same question, but did not found the answer from here:
[Different toolbar for fragments and Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015182/different-toolbar-for-fragments-and-navigation-drawer)

In this post one person ***Wax*** give the solution, but solution cause the memory leak.

Now i want to ask that, how can i achieve this. I have tried many resources, but did not find the solution yet.

Some people are using the BaseActivity approach, but i did not want to try this approach, because this approach requires the inflation of whole NavigationDrawer each time.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi just place a frameLayout below the toolbar of main_activivty.xml.
And now everytime your need to switch from one fragment to another fragment just replace with framelayout id.

Follow these steps :

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.futuretech.animewallhd.Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Nature");
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        replaceFragment(new TopFrag());




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.top) {
            toolbar.setTitle("Nature");
            replaceFragment(new TopFrag());

        } else if (id == R.id.featured) {
            toolbar.setTitle("Love");
            replaceFragment(new FeatureFrag());

        } else if (id == R.id.most) {
            toolbar.setTitle("Featured");
            replaceFragment(new MostFrag());

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    protected void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
    }


}
```

Fragment.java

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,
                container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: But my toolbar is also changing with each fragment . Some fragment have the simple toolbar and some fragments have the collapsing toolbar.And these toolbars should be linked with the Navigation drawer

Comment: remove toolbar from every fragment (except Mainactiviy)

Comment: But the problem still the same. Every fragment toolbar should be synced with the navigation drawer. And every time if i synced the new toolbar the previously synced toolbar cause the memory leak.

Comment: If you also have collapsing toolbar then you have to use two toolbar One for all fragments and one for Collapsing

Comment: And when you remove toolbar from fragment layout also remove toolbar  from Fragment.java you don't need to initialize them every time its enough in MainActivity

Comment: Can you give me concret example i am confused

Comment: Now check the edited answer you will get all thing. If you like please upvote

Answer (score 1):

Put you Navigation drawer layout in main activity and take a frame layout in container section of navigation drawer. Now on each navigation clicks add the new fragment to the drawer container. Make a public method in activity to open drawer. Then add toolbar for each fragment and on toolbar navigation icon call the activity's open drawer method.

Comment: problem is that when i synced the fragment toolbar with the navigation drawer. Then the previously synced toolbar cause the memory leaked.

Comment: Make a common toolbar and include it in all fragments.... And when you want to change fragmnet just replace them

Comment: Every fragment have the different toolbar... i mentioned in question?

Comment: no issue.. for this you have only to call method open drawer.. ret of the code will be independent. there will be no memory leaks because no one is dependent on anyone.

Comment: is there is need to sync the fragment toolbar with the navigation drawer of the MainActivity???

Comment: no not at all.. you just need to set your toolbar inside your fragment which you want to open. you only have to call a method for opening the drawer layout as ((DrawerLayoutActivity)getActivity()).yourDrawerOpenMethod() and thats all

Comment: @ataravati here we can only correct your code if you have any error. We can't write ideal code which can be useful to all users.

Comment: That’s not true.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to take your navigation drawer in the main activity.
Now create separate fragments for every option in your drawer.

No in res folder of your android studio project structure you need to create new folder with name "menu"

In this menu folder, you need to create xml files for every fragment.
Put your items in these menu folders.

---

> Here I have found a tutorial on [android navigation drawer with
>   different toolbar](https://demonuts.com/navigation-drawer-menu-item/)

---

Sample code for file in menu folder can be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_update"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Update Profile"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Logout"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

With this file you can add logout and update options in toolbar.

Fragment code can be like

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {

    public NotificationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.notification_menu, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_update) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        }else if(id == R.id.action_logout){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logout clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```