# Different action bar for each fragment in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer with some fragments attached to it. What I want is to have for each fragment with a separate ActionBar and ToolBar and I don't want the default ActionBar of the navigation drawer to be present when a fragment is pressed for example.

Comment: Please show us how your app is structured (e.g. the layout files)

Comment: I am implementing the default navigation drawer template in android studio, in there it requires me to have a toolbar in the activity Layout I am setting up the drawer, but that toolbar get's present in each fragment I am in, I don't want that, what can I do to have a sperate and different toolbar for each fragment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different toolbar for fragments and Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015182/different-toolbar-for-fragments-and-navigation-drawer)

Comment: I have seen that, but do you have any solutions apart from that?

Comment: Ok, that's not good - I was thinking that the answer by *smbd uknow* should work for you. My other idea was to have an `interface FragmentHost{ setToolbar(Toolbar);}` and to have the Activity implement that interface

Comment: Actually I thought that the answers in that question where not really soluble, but now that I had double checked, I think those solutions can solve my problem, thanks for pointing out.