# Is it possible to attach activity with reside menu in android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, residemenu

I want to attach activity with reside menu, Instead of fragments.
I mean when I will click on reside menu option then it should call activity instead of fragment.
Is it possible?
If possible then how ?

Comment: *Is it possible?* -> Yes it is. *If possible then how ?* -> Please use http://www.google.com

Comment: I dont want to use fragment anywhere with reside menu? I am not getting on google. Can anybody plz help me out?

Comment: How can I use reside menu without fragments? I mean no single fragment should be in project. I am not able to find. If after -ve marking any one could provide me link or could help me...

Comment: has your problem got solved?

Answer (score 1):

What i understand, you want to open activity on menu option clicked and all the activities should have menu options available.

If it is correct, then you need to create on Activity which handle the menu options and extend all the activities with the same activity.

please refer this
[Same Navigation Drawer in different Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities)