# Navigation Drawer doesn't work onBackPressed in different Activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using common navigation drawer for different activities where I am extending BaseActivity , although it works fine but i am unable to open the drawer if I pressed back button to go to the previous activity.

This is my code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public static ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    protected RelativeLayout _completeLayout, _activityLayout;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    Context context;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    ImageView viewImage;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
    private String imgPath;
    private TextView tv_user_name;
    private ProfilePictureView profilepic;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // ---------   login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        //  profilepic = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.fb_profile_pic);
        //  fetchDetailsViaFb();
    }

    public void setNavigationHeader() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_header, null, false);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);
        viewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        tv_user_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name);
        tv_user_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        profilepic = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.fb_profile_pic);
    }

    public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) {
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
        // adding nav drawer items
        if (navMenuIcons == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i]));
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i],
                        navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
            }
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, null, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        setNavigationHeader();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW,
                "Base Page",
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                Uri.parse("android-app://android.sit.findpro/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW,
                "Base Page",
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                Uri.parse("android-app://android.sit.findpro/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Displaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                if(LogInActivity.userLoginViaFb){
                    profilepic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fetchDetailsViaFb();
                }

                viewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                profilepic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                selectImage();


              /*  editor.putString("namePreferance", itemNAme);
                editor.putString("imagePreferance", encodeToBase64(yourBitmap));
                editor.commit();*/

                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "Coming Soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:

                viewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                selectImage();

                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "Coming Soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 4:
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>This is the text that will be shared.</p>"));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle sttate after onResoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void fetchDetailsViaFb(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if (json != null) {
                        String name = json.getString("name");
                        tv_user_name.setText(Html.fromHtml(name));
                        profilepic.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
    private void selectImage() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose Profile Pic");
        builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Take a Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"},
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                                startActivityForResult(intent1, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                // GET IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
        profilepic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    public Uri setImageUri() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                System.out.println("path" + selectedImagePath);
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
                PreferenceHandler.encodeToBase64(decodeFile(selectedImagePath)); //uy7igyoiugo

            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                Toast.makeText(this,"path" + selectedImagePath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("path" + selectedImagePath);
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
               String img= PreferenceHandler.encodeToBase64(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));//uyiyuogo
            PreferenceHandler.writeString(BaseActivity.this,PreferenceHandler.PROFILE_IMAGE,img);
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of
            // 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }

    /* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }else {
          //  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the functionality you want? If I understand correctly you want to open the navigation drawer when the user clicks the back button. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with your code. In `onOptionsItemSelected` there is wrong code. Replace that code with this code and everything should work fine:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // This makes sure the NavigationDrawer gets opened when the upper left button is pressed
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: well i applied this type of code also.. and  yes it open my drawer on backpressed which looks strange

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas What is the problem then if this code works?

Comment: Caused by: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {android.sit.findpro/android.sit.findpro.ProfessionalListActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()

Comment: I want the navigation to open on onResume ie. for other activities. As the navigation freezes if i came back to the activity again

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want the `NavigationDrawer` to open when you return to an `Activity`?

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas Forgot to tag you, don't know if you get notifications otherwise

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas I have changed my answer, I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: I placed this onRestart code in Base Activity class, but same issue still facing

Comment: have you find any solution?

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas Sorry, I don't have a lot of time. Can you tell me what's going on when you try the onRestart code?

Comment: Navigation drawer gets open every time, which doesn't look good on seeing the app. and if I change the functionality like if(drawer open) drawer close, then also navigation gets locked. It doesnot open.  I mean the navigation button, if I slide in between the activity then it gets open, but not via, navigation button'

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas Ahh I think I understand now. I've changed my answer. If you update your code everything should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when you come back on an activity you have to do it in onResume.

Comment: I tried onResume also on the activities, where i am again initiating    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items); // load
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);    But I can see the repeated images in the navigation header

Comment: You have to find your way to deal with activity lifecyle http://images.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png&imgrefurl=http://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity&h=673&w=523&tbnid=O8bNSw7AkWVoKM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=70&docid=CrFxCjdSqznm0M&usg=__mkFGOBmeYYVbw7qUWNnRitjcTlg=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio_cqym8DMAhVIuBQKHc7DCukQ9QEIHjAA

Answer (score 0):

Overiding OnBackPressed in class which is extending BaseClass.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }else {
          //  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```