# Navigation drawer not working on activities using fragments

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I've been trying to add a Nav Drawer to my app. I have this MapsActivty which is my main activity.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

public GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
public void onMapSearch(View view) {
    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
}

public void onNormalMap(View view) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}

public void onSatelliteMap(View view) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
}

public void onTerrainMap(View view) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
}


public void onHybridMap(View view) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
}
public static double lng;
public static double lat;
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), RegistroInfo.class);
            intent.putExtra("longitud", String.valueOf(lng));
            intent.putExtra("latitud", String.valueOf(lat));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } });
    //View v;

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Custom location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            RegistroInfo regis = new RegistroInfo();
            lng = point.longitude;
            lat = point.latitude;

        }

    });

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng cusco = new LatLng(-13.537733, -71.903838);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cusco).title("Cusco, Peru"));
    float zoomLevel = 16; //This goes up to 21
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cusco, zoomLevel));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cusco));


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(true);}}
```

1. NOTICE that a use `extends FragmentActivity`and i saw that i could use `extends MenuActivity` from my MenuActivity I tried this post [[Same Navigation Drawer in different Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities]))
2. From my Menu Activity i have some items, which are the MapsActivity( `nav_MenuPrincipal` ), PerfilActivity(another activity showing information of current user) `nav_perfil`, NormalMap(style of map) `nav_normal`, SatelliteMap(style of map) `nav_satellite, TerrainMap(style of map)`nav_terrainmap`, HybridMap(style of map)`nav_hybrid

Here goes the MenuActivity

```
    public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_MenuPrincipal) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_perfil) {


    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_suggestions) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_normalmap) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_satellitemap) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_terrainmap) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_hybridmap) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_aboutus) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

3. Notice that I've tried this  `if (id == R.id.nav_MenuPrincipal) { startActivity(new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class)); return true; }`, it works but not showing the menu bar.
4. For the items called `Normal, Satellite, Terrain, Hybrid`i just want to change the style of the map for the `MapsActivity`
5. Now I'm using a LoginActivity which is already connected to a DB on a Hosting, it has the intent filter. Then i want to show my MainActivity (MapsActivity) but with that Menu (NavigationDrawer)

Thank you very much.
Sorry if I'm not very clear, its my first time here

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private NavigationView mDrawer;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private Button search;
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    String placeName, address;
    private static final float ALPHA_DIM_VALUE = 0.1f;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        try {
            manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in,
                        R.anim.push_up_out);
            } else {
                mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_out,
                        R.anim.push_up_in);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setupDrawer();

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    private void showErrorToast() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.Toast_Error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.mNavDrawer);
        assert mDrawer != null;
        mDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.DrawerOpen,
                R.string.DrawerClose) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = null;
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_1) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            intent = new Intent(this, LocationList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in,
                    R.anim.push_up_out);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_2) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in,
                    R.anim.push_up_out);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

just copy reliable code.. and have any doubt about Map then ask me.. i have all your solution regarding map.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still have so many errors. Maybe you can help me more with the MapsActivity. There are so many libraries that maybe I'm not exporting.

Comment: What library..? There is no library for map activity

Comment: but yes.. you have to add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'   this dependency

Comment: Well is calling me like an unimplemented methods this: 
`AddGeofenceFragment.AddGeofenceFragmentListener, OnShowcaseEventListener()`

Also is giving me errors this:
`initialize()`

Comment: its seems you are pure newbie..  i m updating my answer now., just remove those things.. that is not usable for you.. i already told you just copy reliable code.

Comment: Really is, It's my first app. :(

Comment: Error `MapsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

Comment: bcz you are already using toolbar, and in my code i m also providing you getSupportActionBar.  look in my setupDrawer() method. so just remove your toolbar code..

Comment: What might be the toolbar code on my MapsActivity code? I couldn't found it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor  just see this link.. and try to figure out your style.xml