# Default navigation drawer on every activity

Tags: android

I am new in android development. i have just created one android project

while creating android project. i selected the type of activity as navigation drawer(i.e .mainactivity).
now i encountered that the activity created new is not containing that drawer. but i want to show that navigation drawer on every activity.
Is that possible?

on googling i found some tutorials but those are for custom navigation drawer. 
any suggestions please? because i don't want to add back button to go back from current activity. i have added home button in drawer menu.

Comment: use a fragment to access drawer in each and every UI. Because fragment is appropriate standard

Comment: you can create BaseActivity with Navigation drawer and extends this BaseActivity in every activity. and Another way is use to framelayout and change fragment on it

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities

Comment: use this github based project https://github.com/Teju068/AndroidnavigationDrawer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:-

Create Baseactivty.java and add following code:-



public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ListView drawerList;
    public String[] layers;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private Map map;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // R.id.drawer_layout should be in every activity with exactly the same id.
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity) this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 0, 0) 
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) 
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        layers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.layers_array);
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_header, null);
        drawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, android.R.id.text1,
                layers));
        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_list_footer, null, false);
        drawerList.addFooterView(footerView);

        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                map.drawerClickEvent(pos);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

extend this Baseactivity to all activity where you want navigationdrawer

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach is using the Navigation Drawer and FragmentManager

1.Create MainActivity and put the DrawerLayout as it's main_content as

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2. Initialise Drawer list

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       private String[] mPlanetTitles;
       private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
       private ListView mDrawerList;


       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
           mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
           mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

           // Set the adapter for the list view
           mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                   R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
           // Set the list's click listener
           mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

       }
   }
   ```
3. Handle Navigation Click Events

   ```
   private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           selectItem(position);
       }
   }

   /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
   private void selectItem(int position) {
       // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
       Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
       fragment.setArguments(args);

       // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                      .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                      .commit();

       // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
       mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
       setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
       mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
   }

   @Override
   public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
       mTitle = title;
       getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
   }
   ```

4 Open and Close Events on NavigationDrawer

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
    }
```

> The other approach is make a BaseActivity put the NavigationDrawer in
>   it then extend the BaseActivity for all of the ChildActivities so you
>   can use the same navigation drawer throughout the app.