# I have my NavigationDrawer working on MainActivity. However when I switch Activites it dissapears

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

Below is the code which I have for my NavigationDrawer. I think it is something to do with parts of my code being public/private or protected. However I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.my_account:
                    //Do code here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_news:
                    //Do code here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_live:
                    //Do code here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_media:
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,activity_main_media.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_calendar:
                    //Do code here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_results:
                    //Do code here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    //Do code here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_shop:
                    //Do code here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_social_media:
                    //Do code here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_fanzone:
                    //Do code here
                    break;

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Do you have DrawerLayout inside second Activity?

Comment: Your drawer is only in mainactivity, if you want it in activity_main_media you need to add it to the layout there

Comment: is that as simple as pasting into my activity_main_media?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation Drawer is belong to an actvitiy. When you switch activitys its normal to lose navbar.You need to use fragment instead of activity.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) is documentation.

However if you still want to use activity for each item on navigation bar you better take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities)