# Android Nav drawer in all activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

**how to show my navigation drawer in all activities**

> After creating a new project in the android studio and have a navigation drawer activity, I run it and it did not show in my all activities. ( I did not add any code, just create 
>   activity and run it). I want to know how to show navigation 
>   drawer in all activities, is there any way ?

Comment: In navigation Drawer Activity Page Use a Fragment

Comment: Follow here, you can successfully implement this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind Navigation drawer with one activity. Navigation drawer will display in only activity in which you have created. if you want to view navigation drawer in all application, you can add one frame layout and add fragments there for application functionality. That app will be a single activity with multiple fragments.

Following is code to add fragment. :

```
 Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
// Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
               .commit();
```

For more details: Check this link. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

**EDIT**

**Without Fragment**

You can create one `BaseActivity`, all `activity` will be extended `BaseActivity`. You need to bind your `navigation drawer` with `BaseActivity`. This way, you can achieve what you want.

**BaseActivity.Java**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DrawerLayout fullView = (DrawerLayout) 
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
    FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) 
    fullView.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
    super.setContentView(fullView);


}
```

}

Comment: Pls tell me without using Fragments

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: pls tell me elaborately

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer? I already have given code snippet of your requirement.

Comment: but how to bind it with nav drawer ?