# RecyclerView onClick stops working when using a navigation drawer (no fragments)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclick, listener

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities/19451842#19451842) post which talks about how to create a navigation drawer without the use of fragments. Keeping aside the motivation of why I don't want to use fragments, I am now facing an issue such that the onClick event for my `RecyclerView` items is no longer getting triggered.

**TL;DR: If I remove the `DrawerLayout` section from my layout xml , the onClick event gets triggered as expected. Defining a `DrawerLayout` in my activity layout xml seems to be causing all events for the RecyclerView such as scrolling/clicking to stop working. Another observation I have is that including the `DrawerLaout` causes the first element of my `RecyclerView` to not be shown at all. I am unable to figure out what could be causing the onClick events to get blocked.**

---

Following is the relevant sections of my code:

**1. NavigationActivity that will be extended by other activities that want the Navigation Drawer to be shown**

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected void onCreateDrawer() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_todays_goals) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_freetime) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,FreeTimeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_goaltime) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,GoalTimeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID)
    {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
        onCreateDrawer();
    }
}
```

**2. One of the activities that extends the NavigationActivity with the problematic RecyclerView (Showing only relevant code) :**

```
public class FreeTimeActivity extends NavigationActivity implements FreeTimeAdapter.FreeTimeAdapterOnClickHandler, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

    private FreeTimeAdapter mFreeTimeAdapter;

    private int mPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_freetime);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_seasons);
        mLoadingIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator);
        mFreeTimeAdapter = new FreeTimeAdapter(this, this);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
                new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFreeTimeAdapter);
        showLoading();
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(FREETIME_LOADER_ID, null, this);

   }

    @Override
    public void onClickFreeTimeListItem(String name) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FreeTimeDetailsActivity.class);
        //TODO uri should be set as freetime_goals rather than goals.
        Uri uri = LifeTimeContract.FreeTimeGoalEntry.CONTENT_URI;
        uri = uri.buildUpon().appendPath(name).build();
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.putExtra("freezone_name",name);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The `onClickFreeTimeListItem` method is the one that should get called when an item in the `mRecyclerView` instance is clicked. I tried debugging the `FreeTimeAdapter` class that is used by the RecyclerView and it seems to register the listener as expected but the `onClick` method is never called later on when the item in the `RecyclerView` is clicked. Following is the code for the `FreeTimeAdapter` class :

```
public class FreeTimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FreeTimeAdapter.FreeTimeAdapterViewHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;

    final private FreeTimeAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

    /**
     * The interface that receives onClickFreeTimeListItem messages.
     */
    public interface FreeTimeAdapterOnClickHandler {
        void onClickFreeTimeListItem(String name);
    }

    private Cursor mCursor;

    /**
     * Creates a ForecastAdapter.
     *
     * @param context      Used to talk to the UI and app resources
     * @param clickHandler The on-click handler for this adapter. This single handler is called
     *                     when an item is clicked.
     */
    public FreeTimeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, FreeTimeAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler) {
        mContext = context;
        mClickHandler = clickHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public FreeTimeAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        int layoutId = R.layout.freetime_list_items;
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layoutId, viewGroup, false);
        view.setFocusable(true);
        return new FreeTimeAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FreeTimeAdapterViewHolder freeTimeAdapterViewHolder, int position) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        String freeTimeName = mCursor.getString(FreeTimeActivity.INDEX_FREETIME_NAME);
        int id = mCursor.getInt(FreeTimeActivity.INDEX_FREETIME_ID);
        String startTime = mCursor.getString(FreeTimeActivity.INDEX_FREETIME_START_TIME);
        String endTime = mCursor.getString(FreeTimeActivity.INDEX_FREETIME_END_TIME);
        String endDate = mCursor.getString(FreeTimeActivity.INDEX_FREETIME_END_DATE);
        freeTimeAdapterViewHolder.tvFreeTimeName.setText(freeTimeName);
        freeTimeAdapterViewHolder.tvStartTime.setText(startTime);
        freeTimeAdapterViewHolder.tvEndTime.setText(endTime);
        freeTimeAdapterViewHolder.tvEndDate.setText(endDate);
        /*FreeTimeItemDataHolder freeTimeItemDataHolder = new FreeTimeItemDataHolder(id,freeTimeName);*/
        freeTimeAdapterViewHolder.itemView.setTag(R.string.tag_freetime_id,id);
        freeTimeAdapterViewHolder.itemView.setTag(R.string.tag_freetime_name,freeTimeName);


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == mCursor) return 0;
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }

    void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        mCursor = newCursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class FreeTimeAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        final TextView tvFreeTimeName;
        final TextView tvStartTime;
        final TextView tvEndTime;
        final TextView tvEndDate;

        FreeTimeAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            //TODO add additional views to each item in the recyclerview such as delete button etc
            tvFreeTimeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_freetime_name);
            tvStartTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_freetime_start_time);
            tvEndTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_freetime_end_time);
            tvEndDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_freetime_end_date);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        /**
         * This gets called by the child views during a click. We fetch the date that has been
         * selected, and then call the onClickFreeTimeListItem handler registered with this adapter
         *
         * @param v the View that was clicked
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            mCursor.moveToPosition(adapterPosition);
            String name = mCursor.getString(FreeTimeActivity.INDEX_FREETIME_NAME);
            mClickHandler.onClickFreeTimeListItem(name);
        }
    }
}
```

**layout xml file for the activity that contains the recycler view**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_loading_indicator"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_seasons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="48dp"
        android:onClick="onClickAddFreeTime"/>

    <!-- Temporariliy added to navigate to goal time screen. Remove this when app navigation bar is coded -->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_all_goals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="48dp"
        android:onClick="onClickAllGoals"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The same codebase was working fine until I introduced the `NavigationActivity` and related navigation drawer code.

Comment: Is there any visual feedback when clicking? Can you scroll the `RecyclerView`? Are you sure you have the `DrawerLayout` set up correctly in the XML?

Comment: @MikeM. You are right. I am unable to scroll the RecyclerView even though there are 100+ items. What do you suspect could be causing this? I edited the post with more information. Any direction would be really helpful.

Comment: Yeah, the layout is a little wacky. You don't want to "layer" the `DrawerLayout` over everything else. It should contain two things: all of the main content over which the drawer opens, and the drawer itself. Your main content is split up, and part of it – including the `RecyclerView` – is ending up underneath the `DrawerLayout`. The `<DrawerLayout>` should be the root, and everything else that is not the drawer – the `<NavigationView>`, in this case – should be inside one `ViewGroup` listed above it; e.g., arranged inside the `app_bar_navigation` layout somehow

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for linking me to the duplicate. Followed your advice of using the `DrawerLayout` as the root and a few changes here and there and the issue was resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi ping actually i don't know what is the wrong exactly in your code but you can take look on my code i did the same and it's working fine
this is the base activity that contain the nav drawer

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout fullLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private int selectedNavItemId;
    List<User> userInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private TextView headerText;
    private TextView pointsTextView;
    private TextView groupTextView;
    String access;
    String client;
    String expiry;
    String uid;
    String type;
    String url;
    ArrayList<String> categories;
    View parentVeiw;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    }
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        parentVeiw=findViewById(R.id.activity_container);
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Snackbar.make(parentVeiw,"الرجاء اضغط مرة أخرى للخروج من البرنامج",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        access = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getAccessToken();
        client = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getClient();
        expiry = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getExpiry();
        uid = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getUid();
        type = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getType();
        url = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getUrl();
        getCategories(url, access, type, client, expiry, uid);
        sendJsonRequestgetUserInfo(url, access, type, client, expiry, uid);



        /**
         * This is going to be our actual root layout.
         */
        fullLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
        /**
         * {@link FrameLayout} to inflate the child's view. We could also use a {@link android.view.ViewStub}
         */
        FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);

        /**
         * Note that we don't pass the child's layoutId to the parent,
         * instead we pass it our inflated layout.
         */
        super.setContentView(fullLayout);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView); //        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; //        if (currentapiVersion == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){ //            toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);  } //

        if (useToolbar())
        {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
        else
        {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        setUpNavView();
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that can be used by child classes to
     * specify that they don't want a {@link Toolbar}
     * @return true
     */
    protected boolean useToolbar()
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected void setUpNavView()
    {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if( useDrawerToggle()) { // use the hamburger menu
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, fullLayout, toolbar,
                    R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close);

            fullLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        } else if(useToolbar() && getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            // Use home/back button instead
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to allow child classes to opt-out of having the
     * hamburger menu.
     * @return
     */
    protected boolean useDrawerToggle()
    {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        fullLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        selectedNavItemId = menuItem.getItemId();

        return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (id)
        {
            case R.id.main:
                Intent mainac = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainac);
                finish();


                break;

            case R.id.Categories:
                Intent Categories=new Intent(this,CategoryActivity.class);
                Categories.putExtra("categories", categories);
                startActivity(Categories);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.notifications:
                Intent notificationIntent=new Intent(this,NotificationsActivity.class);
                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                finish();

                break;
            case R.id.change_password:
                Intent changePassIntent=new Intent(this,changePassword.class);
                startActivity(changePassIntent);
                finish();

                break;
            case R.id.log_out:



                SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(SignInActivity.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit(); //                user = "";
                //show login form
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, First_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                break;
            case R.id.about_them:
                Intent aboutThemIntent=new Intent(this,AboutThem.class);
                startActivity(aboutThemIntent);
                finish();

                break;
            case R.id.about_us:
                Intent aboutUsIntent=new Intent(this,AboutUs.class);
                startActivity(aboutUsIntent);
                finish();

                break;




            default:
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }}
```

**and this is the activity that extend the base activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    public static final int detail_id = 1;

    private bookListAdapter booklistadapter;

    List<book> aksarEste3araList = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView aksarEste3araRecyclerView;

    List<book> sanfMofadalList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView sanfMofadalRecyclerView;

    String user;
    String access;
    String client;
    String expiry;
    String uid;
    String type;
    String url;
    TextView mostEste3aeaNmae, sanfMofadalName;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mostEste3aeaNmae = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.most_este3ara_name);
        sanfMofadalName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sanf_mofadal_name);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GE_SS_Three_Light_0.otf");

        mostEste3aeaNmae.setTypeface(custom_font);
        sanfMofadalName.setTypeface(custom_font);


        access = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getAccessToken();
        client = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getClient();
        expiry = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getExpiry();
        uid = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getUid();
        type = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getType();
        url = ((GlobalVAriables) this.getApplication()).getUrl();


//Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),access,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);


        //        aksar este3ara
        aksarEste3araRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.aksar_este3ara_recycler_view);
        sendJsonRequestAksarEste3ara(url, access, type, client, expiry, uid);
        aksarEste3araRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getBaseContext(), aksarEste3araRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BookDetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("goo", aksarEste3araList.get(position).getCategoryId());
                i.putExtra("bookId", aksarEste3araList.get(position).getBookId());
                startActivityForResult(i, detail_id);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BookDetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("goo", aksarEste3araList.get(position).getCategoryId());
                i.putExtra("bookId", aksarEste3araList.get(position).getBookId());
                startActivityForResult(i, detail_id);

            }
        }));


        //        sanf mofadal
        sanfMofadalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.sanf_mofadal_recycler_view);

        sendJsonRequestSanfMofadal(url, access, type, client, expiry, uid);

        sanfMofadalRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getBaseContext(), sanfMofadalRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BookDetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("goo", sanfMofadalList.get(position).getCategoryId());
                i.putExtra("bookId", sanfMofadalList.get(position).getBookId());
                startActivityForResult(i, detail_id);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BookDetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("goo", sanfMofadalList.get(position).getCategoryId());
                i.putExtra("bookId", sanfMofadalList.get(position).getBookId());
                startActivityForResult(i, detail_id);

            }
        }));

    }
```

please if you need any clarification don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; however, I want to understand what's going wrong in my approach..

Comment: No problem i hoped that i can help more