# How to enable drawer in activity when using custom navigation drawer

Tags: android

I have problem when clicking on a drawer it will navigate to an activity.

```
            if ( (listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition).equals("Fuel"))) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fuel_1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

But when it go the activity , i dont see the drawer . I need to press back then it will see the drawer. How to enable the drawer in activity?

Comment: Show a detailed code of how you are doing it.

Comment: @CoolGuyCG basically i want to display navigation drawer in activity.

Comment: But a lot can still go wrong, so post the code of how you are doing it, then we can see what might be wrong and what needs to be added.

Comment: Navigation drawers are attached to activities. The problem you are facing is that when you move to this new activity, the navigation drawer is not attached to the new activity but the previous activity, that's why you are not seeing it in the new activity. You may want to use fragments or add the navigation drawer to the new activity

Comment: @OrimDominic actually I already use fragment and it is working but unfortunately I have a problem with fragment then want to use activity. Can we simply extends the navigation drawer?Because when if we use interface ,i need to add all the method of navigation drawer in the activity and it make the code too long.

Comment: @MuhammadZawawi yes you can. Check this question [Same Navigation Drawer in different Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your statement. It is required that if you click on any object in your drawer to take you to an activity specified according to your code. But I guess you want to go to the activity while still displaying your navigation bar? or probably for you to go back to your drawer with a back button from your present activity?. If the latter is the case you can do that in your manifest. just edit your present activity in your manifest like this: `<activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >`
name: this should be the name of your present activity.
label: title of your activity.
parentActivityName: this is your Main Activity. the place you want to go back to when you press the back icon.
I hope you understand this

Comment: this is what i want to do " t I guess you want to go to the activity while still displaying your navigation bar?"..is it possible?

Comment: While not use fragment instead of activity to solve this problem once and for all

Comment: you can follow an example from here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: above answer by orindiminic is the best for my situation.Anyways thanks for your comment and help.