# I need advice about what path to take in the creation of a new App

Tags: android

I have an activity with a left pane and I need to change input fields when a different item is selected from the left pane.
I tried by adding a new activity but when the new activity show up the left pane disappears and the only way to get it back is by hitting the back button and I don´t want that; the left pane must hide but must remain to select a new activity and let the user jump from one activity to any other that he choose.

How I cant get that?

I read also about something called fragments but since I'm new on this it looks a bit more complex.

Comment: did you try making the "with left panel" activity a base activity? Therefore all your new activities will have a left panel.

Comment: @fangzhzh I created the App by chossing "Navigation Drawer Activity" in Android Studio. It's Not the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19451842/415673 it briefs both the fragment and the base activity solutions

Answer (score 1):

I would review the documentation on [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui), particularly on using a [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to below Google Navigation Drawer Sample where you could find the correct way of implementing it.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NavigationDrawer

In addition I would recommend exploring bottom navigation, which is like the new navigation trends user enjoys.
Here is a code lab for it:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#0

To choose which component to use for your app follow this material design guideline: https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#lateral-navigation

**Tip:** To Speed up your development you can directly add Navigation Drawer Activity that will help you save a lot of time by adding the base code. Just add new Navigation Drawer activity by right clicking the package.

[image]

Comment: Did you know if exist a compatibility table of the different objects like Navigation Drawer, Bottom Navigation, etc? I need backward compatibility with Android v5 devices.

Comment: @E_Blue - Both are backwards compatible for Android v5 devices (API 21). You should also check out this for better navigation implementation if you are starting by scratch https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#lateral-navigation

Comment: @E_Blue: I have updated my answer, hope it helps you to make better navigation.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting from the scratch, the previous programmer was an external programmer and he lost the source code; so now I'm trying to recreate the app an testing different ways to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Yes using fragments is the best solution. But you can also play around with hiding and showing views.

Comment: With views did you mean activities?