# How to add 2 Navigation Drawer Activities in the same project?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I need to have 2 different navigation drawers. After creating the first one, I click on New Activity to select Navigation drawer. Nothing happens, the gradle syncs and there is only one .xml file in the 'menu' package
Any idea how to solve it?
I have version : 2020.3.1 Patch 2

Comment: Simple is the answer, reuse the same XML file with the `NavigationView` of other `Activity`

Comment: pls following this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19451842/11138845